# Let $a^3 = b^2 + 4 = (b+2i)(b-2i)$. ($a,b$ are integers, $i$ is a complex number). Need to prove ...

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

Given the largest power of $2$ that divides $a$ is $j$, show $(1+i)^{3j}$ is the largest power of the irreducible $(1+i)$ that divides $b+2i$.

I have gotten as far as proving $a^3$ can be factored into $(1+i)^{3j}$ times some other thing, but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Is $i$ a complex number?

Comment: Yes, fixed it !

Comment: Do you mean $b+2i$ instead of $y+2i$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $2 = -i(1 + i)^2$, so $(1 + i)^{6j}$ is largest power of $(1 + i)$ which divides $a^3$.

Now, suppose that $(1 + i)^k \mid (b + 2i)$. Then, since $(b - 2i) = \overline{(b + 2i)}$, and $(1 - i) = \overline{(1 + i)}$, $(1 - i)^k \mid (b - 2i)$. But $(1 - i)^k = (-i)^k(1 + i)^k$, so $(1 + i)^k \mid (b - 2i)$ as well.

Therefore, the largest power of $(1+i)$ dividing $(b+2i)$ is equal to the largest power of $(1+i)$ dividing $(b - 2i)$. Since the total number of factors of $(1+i)$ in $(b+2i)$ and $(b-2i)$ combined must equal $6j$, the largest power of $(1+i)$ dividing each of $(b+2i)$ and $(b-2i)$ must be $(1+i)^{3j}$.